# Retrieving MP4 Video File Stored in Photo Library

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to retrieve a video file I saved in the Photo Album in order to display it in a Table view controller. I have been looking for an answer but I can't seem to find one.

my function to save it to the Album looks like this:

```
@IBAction func saveToAlbum(_ sender: Any) {
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum((completedMoviePath?.path)!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Seems like there is no function that could retrieve the video saved. Can someone please guide me into it?

Comment: That can be achieved using `UIImagePickerController `. Just like you pick images, you can use this controller to pick video as well

Comment: I'm using AVfoundation tho, won't matter right ? Since I'm displaying a video with a UIImageView

Comment: what you do? you create video and saved into photoalbum so please show code when you create video ?

Answer (score 0):

use like this it's working for me fine in swift 3

```
 let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
        let outputURL = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "url")

        if library.videoAtPathIs(compatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum: outputURL as! URL!) {


            library.writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: outputURL as! URL!,completionBlock: { (assetURL:URL?, error:Error?) -> Void in
                //writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: outputURL,completionBlock: { (assetURL:URL!, error:Error?) -> Void in
                var title = ""
                var message = ""
                if error != nil {
                    title = "Error"
                    message = "Failed to save video"
                } else {
                    title = "Success"
                    message = "Video saved"
                }
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
```